# C++ компиляторы

Tags: windows, компилятор, c++

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос. Какой из ниже представленных компиляторов способен генерировать наиболее производительный код для Windows?

1. gcc(mingw)
2. Компилятор от Visual Studio (не знаю как он точно называется)
3. Intel c++

P.S Если вы знаете какой-то другой компилятор, лучше вышеперечисленных - напишите его.

Comment: [Интеловский icc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler) посмотрите еще. Не знаю как с ШИНДОШS, но, скажем, любители собирать Gentoo на скорость говорили, что он дает некий прирост, по сравнению с gcc.

Сам измерением попугаев не занимался, по теме ничего сказать не могу. Разве что стоит не забывать о вечном «We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.»

Comment: по-моему, cygwin - не компилятор. Еще есть компилятор [Intel C++ Compiler](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_compiler).

Comment: @Андрей, погуглил - учту.

Comment: @Андрей cygwin -- действительно не компилятор. Это библиотека, ну и ещё кое-что. Компилятор -- g++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По производительности - конечно Intel C++. Но он таковую дает в первую очередь за счет векторизации и параллелизма. На обычных приложениях выигрыш если и будет, то минимальный.

Кроме того, реальный выигрыш будет на интеловских процессорах. На AMD будет меньше, если вообще будет.

Comment: На счет AMD, вроде есть патч, для бинарников скомпилированных в icc, не пользовались им?

Comment: Нет, не пробовал. Пользуюсь для специальных целей и только на интеловских процессорах. 

Для обработки больших объемов данных обгоняет gcc весьма ощутимо.

Comment: А какой асм там используется для вставок?

Comment: Я в винде интелсиси почти не использовал, пару раз баловался для интереса, ничего сказать не могу про асм. В лине используется синтаксис как в gcc - AT&T. В качестве программы-ассемблера - своя.

Answer (score 4):

К предыдущим ответам хочу добавить, что "наиболее производительный код для Windows", как сформулировал автор, скорее генерирует голова программиста, а компилятор производит его оптимизацию под конкретный CPU, его архитектуру. Оптимизация на уровне архитектуры ПО, как правило, дает существенно больший прирост производительности, чем оптимизация компилятора.

В руководстве по Intel Amplifier говорится, что улучшения дизайна дают прирост до 300%  производительности, в то время как оптимизация на уровне ассемблера, заточка под CPU (чем, по сути, и занимается компилятор) - как правило не более 100%.

Answer (score -1):

когда я сидел под Windows я использовал Dev-cpp
но говорят, что он плохой -- слабая оптимизация и т.п.
тем более, что написан он на Delfi

Comment: Dev-CPP - это IDE, а не компилятор.

Comment: Кстати да)

Comment: просто некоторые написали MS Visual C++ и я подумал, что именно это под компилятором и подразумевается. но все равно я люблю gcc и unix и не люблю использовать IDE

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010